# Ho to add price for attribute related to one group in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am stucked in a situation where in I need to display SUM of all items related to one store. I am unable to do since I am novice to AngularJS.

Data:

```
    [{
      "id": 1,
      "itemName": "PARLE G 500 Grams",
      "itemPrice": 50,
      "minSellPrice": 45,
      "discount": 0,
      "store": "SRI SAI Store"
  }, {
      "id": 10,
      "itemName": "PARLE G 500 Grams",
      "itemPrice": 50,
      "minSellPrice": 46,
      "discount": 0,
      "store": "Ashirwad"
  }, {
      "id": 11,
      "itemName": "PARLE G 500 Grams",
      "itemPrice": 50,
      "minSellPrice": 45,
      "discount": 0,
      "store": "Home Needs"
  }, {
      "id": 2,
      "itemName": "Almond Oil 50 ml",
      "itemPrice": 75,
      "minSellPrice": 67,
      "discount": 0,
      "store": "SRI SAI Store"
  }, {
      "id": 12,
      "itemName": "Almond Oil 50 ml",
      "itemPrice": 75,
      "minSellPrice": 70,
      "discount": 0,
      "store": "Ashirwad"
  }, {
      "id": 13,
      "itemName": "Almond Oil 50 ml",
      "itemPrice": 75,
      "minSellPrice": 65,
      "discount": 0,
      "store": "Home Needs"
  }]
```

HTML COde:

```
<div ng-repeat="player in itemsList | filter:{store: playerPerTeam.store}"  ng-init="setTotals(player)">
</div>

<div class="item item-body">
  <img class="full-image" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-left: 0%" src="img/images1.jpg">
  <p class="pull-right" style="margin-left: 8%; font-size: 20px">
  Total Cart Value: <i class="icon ion-star" style="color: green"><b> {{ invoiceTotal }}/- </b></i>
  </p>
</div>
```

Controller.js code

```
var store = "";
$rootScope.setTotals = function(item){
    store = item.store;

     if (item){
        item.total = 1 * item.minSellPrice;
        alert(item.minSellPrice);
       // $scope.invoiceCount += item.quantity;

            $rootScope.invoiceTotal += item.total ;
       }


    }
```

by this, what I am getting is sum of all items present in response but what I am looking for is sum of only those items related to one store. for example, if SRI STORE has three items, sum shud be of only these 2 and same for other stores

Can anybody help me how to do it?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: You can't work from the `ng-init` value, it will only run once and nothing in your code would ever reset `invoiceTotal`. Numerous ways to do this like `ng-change` , a `$watch` on the filter predicate , creating filtered array object within ng-repeat syntax and watching that ,  creating a custom filter to return the sum based on the filter predicate. Try one of those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print invoice total by store, you can use group by. you don't need ngRepeat to compute total. 
you can do it in controller like this,

```
// this stores object will save invoice total 
$scope.stores = {};

$scope.itemsList.forEach(function(item,index) {
  if(!$scope.stroes[item.store]) {
     // if first time, initialize
     $scope.stroes[item.store] = 0;
  }
  // add item total to store
  $scope.stroes[item.store] += item.total;
});
```

in HTML,

```
<p ng-repeat="(storeName, invoiceTotal) in stores"> 
     invoice total for {{storeName}}  is  {{invoiceTotal}} </p>
```

Check out [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) Argument section for syntax and different ways to use in html.

[array forEach link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

for iterating JSON,

```
angular.forEach($scope.itemsList, function(item,key){
      if(!$scope.stroes[item.store]) {
         // if first time, initialize
         $scope.stroes[item.store] = 0;
      }
      // add item total to store
      $scope.stroes[item.store] += item.total;
    });
```

Comment: can u pls help with a jsfiddle.. it will be really helpful

Comment: {"Home Needs":[{"id":11,"itemName":"PARLE G 500 Grams","itemPrice":50,"minSellPrice":45,"discount":0,"store":"Home Needs"}],"SRI SAI Store":[{"id":1,"itemName":"PARLE G 500 Grams","itemPrice":50,"minSellPrice":45,"discount":0,"store":"SRI SAI Store"}],"Ashirwad":[{"id":10,"itemName":"PARLE G 500 Grams","itemPrice":50,"minSellPrice":46,"discount":0,"store":"Ashirwad"}]}

Comment: you can use angular.forEach      for iterating JSON same as array...                                   you can find correct syntax here.    https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: a jsfiddle will be great help Raj. I know I shud try this first but I am running out of time ,, hence the questions and help requested

Comment: I am not able to edit existing plunkr. but adding to answer

Comment: @AngryJS, as I understand your JSON strucure, I have made change to plunkr example link.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a watch on `playerPerTeam.store` then calculate total price there:

*Assuming `data` variable has list of items*

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.playerPerTeam = {
                store: ""
            };
            $scope.$watch("playerPerTeam.store", function (newValue) {
                var total = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (data[i].store === newValue) {
                        total += data[i].itemPrice;
                    }
                }
                $scope.invoiceTotal = total;
            });
        });
```